# RegisterHotKey makes my CapsLock stuck

Tags: c#, wpf

this is kinda strange for me. I made a dummy c# program in my house a while ago (PC) and it worked 100%, I mean the hotkeys. Numlock and Capslock worked perfectly fine. Now, I'm continuing my program here in my laptop, and apparently the RegisterHotKey function makes my capslock stuck. NUMLOCK in my laptop works so fine.

For instance, before I run my program, I check in my notepad if my capslock is on, so I'm gonna type a letter, say the capslock is confirmed to be ON. And then I'm going to run the program, I press the capslock and then type a letter in notepad. The result is that the last state of the capslock before I run the program REMAINS the same. Even if I press capslock many times again. Lastly, if I comment out the line RegisterHotKey(...., 0x14 for CAPSLOCK); and then turning off and on the capslock works fine. And if I stop the program, capslock works fine too.

take note that my laptop has no led indicator for the lock keys.

Whole codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace CapslockNotifier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        DispatcherTimer timer;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        private const int HOTKEY_ID = 9000;
        private const uint VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90;
        private const uint MOD_CTRL = 0;
        private const uint VK_CAPITAL = 0x14;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            MouseDown += delegate { DragMove(); };
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mainForm_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Popup1.IsOpen = false;
            timer.Stop();
        }

        HwndSource source;
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

            IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle);
            source.AddHook(HwndHook);

            RegisterHotKey(handle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_CTRL, VK_CAPITAL); //caps lock
            RegisterHotKey(handle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_CTRL, VK_NUMLOCK); //num lock
            //
        }

        private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
            switch (msg)
            {
                case WM_HOTKEY:
                    switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                    {
                        case HOTKEY_ID:
                            int vkey = (((int)lParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                            if (vkey == VK_CAPITAL)
                            {
                                if (Console.CapsLock == true)
                                {
                                    McTextBlock.Text = "Capslock is ON";
                                    Popup1.IsOpen = true;
                                    timer.Start();
                                    //MessageBox.Show("capslock is ON!!!");
                                }
                                if (Console.CapsLock == false)
                                {
                                    McTextBlock.Text = "Capslock is OFF";
                                    Popup1.IsOpen = true;
                                    timer.Start();
                                    //MessageBox.Show("capslock is ON!!!");
                                }

                            }
                            if (vkey == VK_NUMLOCK)
                            {
                                if (Console.NumberLock == true)
                                {
                                    McTextBlock.Text = "NumLock is ON";
                                    Popup1.IsOpen = true;
                                    timer.Start();
                                }
                                if (Console.NumberLock == false)
                                {
                                    McTextBlock.Text = "NumLock is OFF";
                                    Popup1.IsOpen = true;
                                    timer.Start();
                                }
                            }

                            handled = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            source.RemoveHook(HwndHook);
            source = null;
            UnregisterHotKey(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, HOTKEY_ID);
            base.OnClosed(e);
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Is the HwndHook method being called when you press the caps lock key?

Comment: In your calls to `RegisterHotKey` shouldn't the hotkey ID number be different for the two keys? Also, you've declared `MOD_CTRL` as having value `0`, when the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) state that its value should be `0x0002`. For consistency you should remove `MOD_CTRL` and just use the constant value `0` if you don't want any modifier keys.

Comment: @MikeEason - I don't know sir. Someone from my question in microsoft forum gave me the whole codes.
Steven - Thanks for the comment. It's fine to assign 0 to MOD_CTRL, whether there is consistency or not, the program doesn't still work. :( I'm certain that this program works in the PC (which has led indicators for lock keys). But in my laptop, only the numlock works well. I tried using different hotkey ID but it doesn't work, only 9000 value works.

Comment: It is the eternal keyboard question.  Keyboard input is *buffered*, it ensures that you can still reliably check the state of other keys by the time your program is ready to handle the KeyDown notification.  So you can reliably detect, say, Alt+F1.  That buffered state doesn't get updated until you read that notification.  Trouble is, you didn't, you relied on *another* process to tell you that a key was pressed.  You still see the old state.  Pinvoking GetAsyncKeyState() is a band-aid.

Comment: Can you help me Mr. Hans to implement that Pinvoking in my codes above? Sorry but I have no knowledge much yet in hotkeys, what I can only do is to read the codes and understand it a bit and then modify it.